# Xbox 360 unable to read disc

Tags: xbox-360

I recently bought and installed FIFA 13 to my Xbox 360, but whenever I try to play it, it says it can't read disk. I've cleaned the disk many times and done everything I can think of. I've had my Xbox for 2 years. How can I play the game without acquiring another Xbox?

Comment: I removed the FIFA 13 tag as this doesn't specifically relate to any one game

Comment: Just to clarify, does the disk have any scratches or is there a crack in the center ring?

Comment: Try to install the game? I think you press "Y" to do that

Comment: You don't say if other games work. If they do, it's likely a problem with the disc and you should return it to where you got it from. If the console won't read any discs, it's an issue with the console. You may be able to get it repaired.

Comment: Is there a ring burn in on the disc?

Answer (score 1):

You can polish the disk as here:

Otherwise, you can get another disk (friend, rent, etc).

Comment: Next time, try to clarify things that happen in the video. An answer should be valid even when for example Youtube goes down.